# Double jump in box2D libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I started with Box2D and LibGDX, and I have a character max 2 times, the first jump is 2 meters high, while in the air in the range of 0 - 2 meters, it allows to jump again with a height of 1 And, I'm having a problem in the second jump, when my character does not jump exactly 1 meter as I ordered when it was in free fall. How can my character always jump one meter high while in the air, though it is flying up or down. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying your player can double jump only while the player is going upwards and not while the player is falling? If not so, i am kind of not clear what your problem is.

Comment: I did that, but how do I determine the 1m jumper exactly 2 meters corresponding to the pixel unit and this in every kind of device.

Comment: I use it to jump:
Private void jump () {
         Vector2 position = body.getPosition ();
         Body.applyLinearImpulse (0, Constants.IMPULSE_JUMP, position.x, position.y, false);
     }